# getting the count of another table values in existing query Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

Currently I am doing this to get data from my tables as

```
cameras = Camera.joins("left JOIN users on cameras.owner_id = users.id")
                .joins("left JOIN vendor_models vm on cameras.model_id = vm.id")
                .joins("left JOIN vendors v on vm.vendor_id = v.id")
                .where(condition).order(sorting(col_for_order, order_for)).decorate
```

And this generates such query as

```
SELECT "cameras".* FROM "cameras" left JOIN users on cameras.owner_id = users.id left JOIN vendor_models vm on cameras.model_id = vm.id left JOIN vendors v on vm.vendor_id = v.id
```

I have an other table as `camera_shares` on which I have relation of camera's table as there is a `camera_id` which is present in `camera_shares` table as well, in each `camera_shares` there is an `camera_id` which tell us that the share is for which camera, I want to calculate the count of `camera_shares`, For example if there is a camera with id `12` and there are also 20 `camera_shares` with `camera_id` = `12` then I want to count the total of it. I want to do that in Rails query as I have shown above? How is that possible to do?

Answer (score -1):

Seems rather straightforward. Suppose you want to find the number of camera_shares for @camera:

```
CameraShare.where(camera: @camera).count
```

Comment: why the downvote? Please feel free to leave a comment if there's anything wrong with my answer.

Comment: I know how i can do that in the way you mentioned above. BUT i want it in the query with `joins`, I am looking a way in which i can use `count` in active records to get that

Comment: You meant you want to use Camera.joins(...) to do it? That won't work, no matter what you joins. Because the query will select 'cameras', not 'camera_shares'.